# Looping through columns and rows to count specific values

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with around 27,000 columns and 40,000 rows. I need to count the number of `0.0`s in each column and in each row of the data. I have written the following code to count and print the number of `0.0`s within each column:

```
awk '{a[$1]++;} END{for(i in a) print a[i]"  "i}' file_name.txt
```

I tried to integrate the following code:

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=NF; i>=2; --i) printf "%s ", $i; print $1 }' file_name.txt
```

in order to create a loop where all the `0.0`s were counted and printed. It is not necessary for me to create an output file for the final numbers.

Comment: Give a small example of what the output may look like. Should the output be organised in any particular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [my recent answer](/a/473672/72456) but here we need to check if the field value is match with `0.0` and count both column and rows into separate array instead of sum-up, so:

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i=="0.0") { zero_in_column[i]+= 1 ; zero_in_row[NR]+= 1 }; }
}
END { for (X in zero_in_row)
         print "in_row:"X, zero_in_row[X], "in_column:" X, zero_in_column[X]
}' OFS='\t' infile
```

**Note:** replace `zero_in_row` array with `zero_in_column` in `END { for (X in zero_in_row)` if number_of_column > number_of_rows.

for the input like below (*and I had `END { for (X in zero_in_column)` since my column count is larger than rows count*):

```
1    0.0  3    0.0  4    0.0  0.0
3    4    5    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

The output is:

```
in_row:1        4       in_column:1     1
in_row:2        4       in_column:2     2
in_row:3        7       in_column:3     1
in_row:4                in_column:4     3
in_row:5                in_column:5     2
in_row:6                in_column:6     3
in_row:7                in_column:7     3
```

Comment: The `END` block here assumes that there are as may columns as rows, or that there are at least as many rows as columns.

Comment: Yeah, already explained in such a way and understandable in my answer, It can be validate before loop but no useful when you know your file column and rows, so I ignored

Answer (score 2):

Why not (small adaption to devWeek's proposal, **untested**):

```
awk '
        {ROWCNT = 0
         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "0.0")  {COLCNT[i]++
                                                  ROWCNT++
                                                 }
         print "Row", NR,":", ROWCNT
        } 
END     {for (i=1; i in COLCNT; i++) print "Col", i,":", COLCNT[i]
        }
' file
```

to keep the order of input lines, as the order in which array elements are retrieved is not defined.

Comment: that's broken; it will print the number of rows and number of cols irrespective of the content of the cells ;-)

Comment: Rats - one "=" too few in the `if` - corrected. Thanks @mosvy